# facebook type status and comment using ajax, jquery in asp.net mvc3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

i am working on status update and commenting application in asp.net mvc3 like Facebook wall and comment. User can comment my wall and all stuff like Facebook.

http://demos.99points.info/facebook_wallpost_system/

like above demo, i want to create my application.
how can i do that using mvc3 and ajax?

i successfully updated user status to database but cant get all status updates of same user, i want to use partial view to display all status of user below the status textarea.
and if user write some status and share status that time status message saved in database and again reflect to same view Asynchronously.

how can i do that using ajax?

Comment: Removed the Facebook tag, as you're not asking for help with any Facebook technologies or APIs

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this in broad terms as I don't have any knowledge of asp.net or mvc3. However, it seems to me that you're looking for more architectural direction.

You will need to setup an endpoint which generates the status page, call it `/status.asp`. This will create the text area and load the existing status messages from your database.

Then create a second endpoint, say `/api/status.asp`. This is not a view, but an API in your application that let's a user create (and, if you want, retrieve/modify/delete?) a status.

When a user hits enter in the textarea, fire off an XHR request to `/api/status.asp` with the new status. It is common, but not required, to do this as a POST request (read up on REST - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer). This API should then save the new status to your DB, and return the uid of the status along with the status message, perhaps as JSON (or XML or YAML if you prefer, it's up to you). For example, in JSON:

```
{
  status: [
      {
        uid: '1234567890987654321'
        msg: 'Hello World'
      }
  ]
}
```

(To send the XHR request it's easiest to use a JS library like Dojo ( http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/xhr.html#dojo-xhr ) or JQuery ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ).)

When your XHR request returns, check the status is a 200 (everything went OK), then read the data returned. Write some Javascript to create a new DOM node, inject the status message into that DOM node and add it to the bottom of the previous status nodes.

Bonus Points:

If you want person B to be looking at person A's `/status.asp` page and for that page to auto-update when person A posts a new status, you'll need to do a little more work. Firstly, modify `/api/status.asp` to return a list of the last x (say, 10?) status updates when called via HTTP GET. Include the UID of each status along with the status text.

Call your `/api/status.asp` API repeatedly* (perhaps with a timestamp of the last time you called it, and get your API to only return status posts after that time), loop over the the results and check to see if that post is already included in the users page (perhaps by having an id on each DOM node matching the UID of the status). If not, add it to the page.

*you have a number of options for doing this. For example, simply setup a JS timeout (easy, but not very efficient), or use Comet (eg http://cometd.org/) or WebSockets ( http://websocket.org/ ). I'd go for a timeout first, get it working and then figure out if a better technology is required.